# Удаление символа перехода на новую строку

Tags: java

Читается из файла текст такого формата:

```
строка

строка

строка
```

Затем нужно записать прочитанный текст в следующем формате:

```
строка
строка
строка
```

Файл читаю через Files.readAllLines. Затем через стримы заменяю (replaceFirst потому что, как мне видится, там стоит два подряд идущих символа переноса \n\n, но, раз у меня ничего не выходит, я ошибаюсь на этот счёт).

```
  .map(e -> e.replaceFirst("\n", ""))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

В итоге никакой замены не происходит.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `два подряд идущих символа переноса \n\n` два переноса подряд при чтении `readAllLines` будут означать разные строки же, нет? Типа как определяется граница строки? Символом переноса. ОДна строка имеет только 1 символ переноса строки максимум в файле и не имеет никаких переносов при чтении через `readAllLines`. То есть этот символ переноса скорее всего не будет включен в `readAllLines`, так как в этом смысла нет никакого.

Comment: что вам надо, так это 1) считать все строки 2) отфильтровать все пустые строки 3) записать результат обратно

Answer (score 1):

[`Files::readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) возвращает *список* строк, включая пустые, поэтому проще такие строки удалить, используя [`List::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```java
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path_to_file"));
lines.removeIf(String::isEmpty);
```

Также можно отфильтровать пустые строки из *потока* строк, который можно получить при помощи метода [`Files::lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) и сохранить в новый список:

```java
List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("path_to_file"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()) // в Java 11+ filter(Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```